# On how android custom recovery programs are made

Tags: android, adb, recovery

"adb" has the option of flashing custom recovery image so that one can replace the stock recovery. I was wondering what all criteria a program should meet in order to be flashed as a custom recovery program. For example, just for the sake of experiment, can I flash my "hello world" code instead of CWM or TWRP.

Comment: Just unpack CWM or TWRP and see what is inside. Usually these are blobs created with tools like mkbootimg, containing ext4 filesystem. This filesystem usually contains kernel, scripts and utilities forming an Android-like micro OS.